# Nested SQL within the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please find the below tables data.

**Tran Table**

| UniqueID | Child | Parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40647 | 40643 |
| 2 | 40645 | 40644 |
| 3 | 42742 | 42741 |
| 4 | 40646 | 40643 |
| 5 | 40643 | 40642 |
| 6 | 42741 | 42740 |
| 7 | 40644 | 40642 |
| 8 | 40643 | 40642 |
| 9 | 42740 | 40644 |
| 10 | 40644 | 40642 |

**Offe Table**

| UniqueID | HProp | Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40647 | 70 |
| 2 | 40645 | 70 |
| 3 | 42742 | 20 |
| 4 | 40646 | 70 |
| 5 | 40643 | 80 |
| 6 | 42741 | 40 |
| 7 | 40644 | 80 |
| 8 | 40643 | 80 |
| 9 | 42740 | 70 |
| 10 | 40644 | 80 |

Below is the SQL written it has multiple joins with the same table. Is there any other way to do it bcoz the above joins will continue for another 6 times. If i dont know the parent and child levels, how do i automate it ?

Please help me with this.

```
Select
Case when IV.level=80 then IV.Code
     When IV1.level=80 then IV1.Code
     When IV2.level=80 then IV2.Code
     When IV3.level=80 then IV3.Code else '' End as FinalCode,
Case when IV.level=80 then IV.level
     When IV1.level=80 then IV1.level
     When IV2.level=80 then IV2.level
     When IV3.level=80 then IV3.level else '' End as Finallevel
from Offe FD
left join tran FT on FD.Hprop=FT.Child
left join Offe IV on IV.Hprop=FT.Parent  
left join Tran FT1 on FT.Parent=FT1.Child
left join Offe IV1 on FT1.Parent=IV1.OffeID 
left join Tran FT2 on FT1.Parent=FT2.Child
left join Offe IV2 on FT2.Parent=IV2.OffeID 
left join Tran FT3 on FT2.Parent=FT3.Child
left join Offe IV3 on FT3.Parent=IV3.OffeID
```

Comment: YOu need to use an rCTE. Have a search for hierarchical data solutions in SQL Server.

Comment: I have used a nested set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model by replacing ParentId with Left and Right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't include the specific expected result, and the result you want is not clear from your example. Anyway, a simple recursive CTE will "walk the graph" in multiple levels automatically.

You'll probably need to add some filtering to select the specific rows, and some post-processing to show/format the data as you want it, but the query should take the general form:

```
with
n as (
  select o.level, o.code, t.parent
  from offe o
  join tran t on t.child = o.hprop
 union all
  select o.level, o.code, t.parent
  from n
  join offe o on o.hprop = n.parent
  join tran t on t.child = o.hprop
)
select * from n -- tweak this SELECT as needed
```